# Save text input to a variable in a kivy app

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, python-3.6

I am making a text based game, and there is a point at which the game asks the user to input their surname. I have worked out a way to save the name to a file, and load the name from the file, but I do not know how to save the text that has been input into a variable. I have tried various methods i have seen online, but none have worked for me so far. The section of my code in question currently looks like this: (ignore the odd names like customwidget, i was experimenting once and left them like that :P)

**testing.py file:**

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.9.0")
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class CustomWidget(Widget):
    last_name_text_input = ObjectProperty()
    ego = NumericProperty(0)
    surname = ''

    def submit_surname(self):
        surname = self.last_name_text_input.text

class CustomWidgetApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CustomWidget()

customWidget = CustomWidgetApp()
customWidget.run()
```

**customwidget.kv file:**

```
<CustomWidget>:
    last_name_text_input: last_name
    Label:
        text: "Last Name:"
        pos: 655,400
        size: 100, 30
    TextInput:
        id: last_name
        pos: 760,400
        size: 100, 30
    Button:
        text: "Save Name"
        pos: 870,400
        size: 100, 30
        on_release: root.submit_surname()
```

This creates a screen like this:

[image]

However, whenever I save the surname value to the file or try to print surname, it comes up with nothing. It would be greatly appreciated if I could recieve some help with this issue. Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: This works fine for me, how are you trying to print/save to file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare surname as StringProperty. Please refer to the example below.

## main.py

```
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
    from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, StringProperty


    class CustomWidget(Widget):
        last_name_text_input = ObjectProperty()
        ego = NumericProperty(0)
        surname = StringProperty('')

        def submit_surname(self):
            self.surname = self.last_name_text_input.text
            print("Assign surname: {}".format(self.surname))
            self.save()
            self.surname = ''
            print("Reset surname: {}".format(self.surname))
            self.load()
            print("Loaded surname: {}".format(self.surname))

        def save(self):
            with open("surname.txt", "w") as fobj:
                fobj.write(str(self.surname))

        def load(self):
            with open("surname.txt") as fobj:
                for surname in fobj:
                    self.surname = surname.rstrip()


    class CustomWidgetApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return CustomWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    CustomWidgetApp().run()
```

## customwidget.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<CustomWidget>:
    last_name_text_input: last_name
    Label:
        text: "Last Name:"
        pos: 655,400
        size: 100, 30
    TextInput:
        id: last_name
        pos: 760,400
        size: 100, 30
    Button:
        text: "Save Name"
        pos: 870,400
        size: 100, 30
        on_release: root.submit_surname()
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: I think the most important change is the `self` in front of the `surname`. Making it a StringProperty surely is a good idea, but not strictly neccessary.

Comment: It seems that the lack of both 'StringProperty' and 'self' were the problems. I happened to use 'self' when working with integer values but it didn't occur to me to use it for the text variables as well. Thanks for the help :)